# react router v4 child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
import React from 'react';
import { IndexRoute, Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import Home from './containers/Home';
import App from './containers/App';

export default (
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Background} from '../App/App.style'


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
        {console.log(this.props.children)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

What alternative for these code in routerV4
i want Home component as a child of App Component 
what will use instead of IndexRoute?

Comment: please provide more details about the question...

Answer (score 0):

This is how react-router v4 works.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from '../App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
       <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
       </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Then for Home, import it into `App` component and render it:

```
import Home from './Home'
export default class App extends Component {
...
    render(){
        <Home />
    }
}
```

If ypu plan to have multiple children within app maybe `Home` and `About` within `App` use:

```
<Switch>
     <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
     <Route path="/about" component={About} />
</Switch>
```

Found [this repo](https://github.com/kimobrian/React-Setup) very helpful.